# Number of vertices after taking out an edge from a tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I have a tree (v is number of vertex and d is the maximum  degree)whose maximum degree is $\geq 2$. I want to show that, if I take out an specific edge from this tree, I'll get $2$ trees whose number of the vertex in each tree is no more than $$\frac{v(d-1)}d$$

Comment: Is $v$ the number of vertices, and $d$ the maximum degree of your tree?

Comment: In maths there are no standard letters like $H_2O$ or $\vec F$. You should specify what are $v$ and $d$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I'll edit